# Interval of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Find the interval of convergence of

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac {n^{2n}}{(2n)!}x^{n}$

I use ratio test and i found

$\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|<1$

iff

$-\frac{4}{e^2}<x<\frac{4}{e^2}$.

But at the end points $x=\frac{-4}{e^2}$ and $x=\frac{4}{e^2}$ i have trouble, which convergence test should i use to prove the convergence at the end points.

Comment: Problem at the points $x=\frac{-4}{e^2}$ and $x=\frac{4}{e^2}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Use the Stirling approximation
$$n!\sim_\infty\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$$

Comment: But sorry i don"t know what is $(2n)!$ by the stirlings approximation

Comment: Just replace $n$ by $2n$

Comment: If i replace n by 2n in stirling approximation then i will have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac {n^{2n}}{(2n)!}\frac{4^{n}}{e^{2n}} $~$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi n}}$

Comment: Then it is obviously divergent.

Comment: Right! and for $x=-4e^{-2}$ what do you find? @RizwanAhmed

Comment: For $x=\frac{-4}{e^2}$ i will use Leibnitz alternating series test and it is convergent

Comment: So interval of convergence is [$x=\frac{-4}{e^2}$,$x=\frac{4}{e^2}$).Am i right?

Comment: That's right!${}$@RizwanAhmed

Comment: Thank you very much so i learn about the stirling approximation.Thanks